# C# How to declare passed parameter being added to an Action<>?

Tags: c#, delegates

So I want to store a multicast Action in a class and pass the methods called to it from a class method that modifies the class's private Action object:

```cs
public class Bar;

public class Xzxxy
{
    public delegate void BarDelegate(Bar bar);
    private Action<Bar> BarAction;

    public void Add(BarDelegate bd)
    {
        BarAction += bd;
    }

    public void Invoke(Bar bar)
    {
        BarAction.Invoke(bar);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because in `Xzxxy.Add` the line `BarAction += bd;` has the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert `Xzzzy.BarDelegate` to `System.Action<Bar>`.

How should I declare `BarDelegate` to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution

```cs
public void Add(BarDelegate bd)
{
    BarAction += (bar)=>bd(bar);
}
```

or better is passing `Action<Bar>` to the Add method

```cs
public void Add(Action<Bar> bd)
{
    BarAction += bd;
}
```

The definition for `BarDelegate` is useless and redundant ... because `Action<Bar>` is a delegate that take `Bar` class as a parameter and return `void` you don't need to define new delegate for this!

Comment: Too simple. :) .... :)